# Github style permissions - Multi-tenant or complex Authorizations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, pundit, cancancan

I’m building a multi-tenant application using Rails 4, Postgres, and Devise. Act as Tenant is being used for the partitioning, and devise for authentication. I haven’t chosen an authorization scheme, but leaning towards Pundit.

I had a feature request to allow external users, and these users may be a member of another tenant. Imagine Company A is creating a document. They want to collaborate on it with a user from Company B. The specific user in Company B should only have access to the single specific document within Company A that they are collaborating on, as well as all of Company B’s stuff….

Github does an excellent job of this type of feature allowing the addition of aribitray users into a project with excellent permissions.

So a couple of specific questions. Does this require abandoning a multi-tenant scheme, and going with a somewhat complex authorization scheme. I say abandoning because act_as_tenant provided a somewhat immutable partition of data…

If so would Pundit be the recommended approach (maybe CAnCanCan), or is there some place else I should look?